What are the risks of a compromised top tube and of attempts to repair it?
I understand that the top tube undergoes mostly compression (rather than tension or twisting) forces. My question is: what happens if a top tube is compromised? What are the risks?
For context, I'm looking into doing a carbon repair. My bike had a crack in the top tube, and after I sanded away the damaged material, it now has a small hole in the middle of the top of the top tube. I'm wondering whether it would be dangerous to ride this bike after an imperfect repair.
I'll outline what I would do if I DIY'ed the repair:

fill the area under the hole with some expandable polyurethane closed-cell foam. let it dry, sand it down, paint with epoxy and let it cure.
apply scarf sanding technique to make sure it's gradually tapered to the hole.
do the carbon layup as recommended, including with woven carbon fiber, marine-grade epoxy, and compress using shrink release tape. overbuild slightly just in case.
sand smooth.

What about this procedure could be the failing point vs going to a pro? In particular, is there any danger in overbuilding the top tube?
It's not going to be industry-standard, and I don't have experience with composites. (I have done a lot of reading and youtube-watching, but that doesn't replace industry knowledge, obviously.)

If you decide that it is good enough, you could do a few bunny hops in a safe area just to check if it cracks under trivial loads. This does not mean it won't break later over time, but a bad repair could fail on the first ride.

@jpa thanks. do you know whether a bad repair is more prone to fatigue and degradation over time, or just acute forces?

I would assume yes, but I have to admit I have no real knowledge about it. Inconsistent glue joint could concentrate stress to smaller areas, which would then wear faster.

I've rewritten my answer since the question was extensively edited.
I'll preface this by saying that I'm by no means a qualified carbon fiber repairperson, just someone with some minimal knowledge about composite manufacture. I believe the greatest danger (in terms of safety) of overbuilding the repair is concentrating stresses at the ends of the repaired section. I believe it's possible to mitigate this by carefully tapering the edges (the inner layers of the repair should extend further than the outer layers such that there is a smooth transition into the original frame tubes).
As for the actual failure mode, that is difficult to predict. In the best case, your repair starts falling apart for whatever reason and there's a lot of audible and visible cracking and fibers fraying apart. In the worst case, you hit a pothole or land a drop funny or something and the overload exceeds the (weakened) frame's ultimate strength and it folds up on you. Actual failure behavior will probably lie somewhere between those extremes.
Your procedure sounds reasonable, but you should be sure that you know how to perform each step correctly and confidently. There's a lot of fine details:

How exactly do you perform the foam injection?
Any surface prep other than sanding?
Epoxy mix ratio and mixing technique? Degassing?
How will you control the resin to fiber proportion and avoid voids?
Layup schedule--what combination of unidirectional and woven plies will you use, and in what orientations will you use them?

Maybe purchase some carbon tubes to practice on beforehand (and perform some mechanical testing on the repairs afterwards). Note that even if structurally sound, the frame's riding characteristics may be marginally different due to the change in stiffness. I suppose that's better than having no frame, but it might be something to keep in mind.
If you do proceed with the repair, the best approach might be to significantly overbuild right over the damaged area, and then provide a generous taper to reduce stress concentrations. This should give you a fairly high safety factor that will give you a buffer against technique errors.

Old answer:
That the top tube is under compression also means it's more sensitive to damage because buckling is a concern. If your top tube fails, the bike will pretty much fold in half. And uh, if your cracked top tube now has a hole in it after sanding down (why?) the damaged area, "an imperfect repair" is probably quite a generous description of your situation. I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but it sounds like you've bitten off more than you can chew. I'd suggest to either let a professional handle the repair or to scrap the frame.

sorry, that was a legitimate typo. compression. and by imperfect repair, i don't mean the current state, i mean after i do the repair. my question is about what can happen to the top tube if it's overbuilt, if there's inconsistent forces, or if there is damage deeper inside the tube.

see the edit for what I mean by imperfect repair.

"If your top tube fails, the bike will pretty much fold in half." So is this something that could happen gradually over time, or is that a frontal impact thing? And if there were a big frontal impact that folded the TT, would it not be just as dangerous with a normal TT? (I mean, the bike and I would be hitting some object together, so is it a danger of the TT impaling me, or something else?)

Normal riding exerts substantial stresses on a frame. Most frame failures manifest suddenly and catastrophically while riding, often with little to no visual indications of gradually progressing damage. This is why by the time a frame flaw is observed, it's time to replace it or have an expert repair it. A bad repair will concentrate stresses on that point by making it less flexible (or sometimes more) than the material around it, which only hastens failure. Your bike spontaneously folding in half while accelerating or cornering or hitting a small bump = a bad time.

@JayMcEh thanks for the input! that does sound scary. I thought that carbon would usually crack before catastrophically folding in half... I've never heard of that happening before. do you know anything about what it is about a bad repair that can cause that kind of failure?

@900edges Everyone seems to forget that the downtube is a massive pipe that handles most of the forces. If you do a crap repair on your toptube, it will break again eventually but it is exceptionally unlikely that the bike "will fold in half" without warning.

@Noise yeah, I originally figured the top tube isn't a hugely-stressed component so it would be fine, but I've been having doubts. what do you think would be the cause of the TT breaking eventually? fatigue over time, or a single bad blow to it?

@900edges Updated the answer. At first I thought you were somewhat careless (and confidently incorrect) and were asking "how do I salvage this repair attempt after accidentally sanding all the way through the frame" and made my answer a little more flamboyant to try to dissuade you from further disaster. With the updated question your proposal sounds a lot more reasonable. Also, could you add some photos? Just how much damage are we talking about, and how big is the hole?

I have seen various where the root cause is usually impact damage of some type and another where a crack grew along the length of the top tube over weeks of the bike being used which could have been fatigue or small impact damage allowed to propogate. I have seen various repairs to top tubes of the type you propose done professionally and often not at particularly high cost which suggests the time and materials and tooling are not particularly costly, therefore achievable by a determined and capable DIYer who is prepared to take a risk @900edges

@MaplePanda thank you for the detailed answer. i appreciate the bullet points, which I'll look into. Would you mind expanding on your instruction "the inner layers of the repair should extend further than the outer layers such that there is a smooth transition into the original frame tubes"?

@900edges Think of a pyramid—wider at the bottom, narrower at the top. You don’t want the repair to look like a cast on a broken arm. There should be a smooth transition. If you look at pics of professional carbon repairs, there’s pretty much no seam. This should help avoid stress concentrations caused by an excessively stiff/overbuilt repair.

@MaplePanda I think I understand what you're saying, but I had seen the opposite (upside down pyramid) in images of scarf sanding repair -- e.g. https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0263822322010704-gr1.jpg

@900edges Ah interesting. The idea is somewhat similar though: to not have a sharp transition between the repair and original material. To be honest I wouldn’t know if it’s better to do a repair that’s flush with the surface like this, or one that protrudes like I was envisioning. Probably worthy of future research. Feel free to have more extended discussion in the [chat].

Well, answering the general structural question, I don't know what orientation and magnitude of forces the TT bears while riding. Your understanding may be correct. Or it may be wrong, or it may be incomplete, or it may be wrong in some circumstances, and those might turn out to be edge cases (and you might run into one of them in the field) or they might turn out not to be edge cases (increasing the chance you run into them in the field).
Say you didn't clean the area thoroughly, which you need to do so that the new sheets will adhere to the undamaged parts. As you ride over bumps, your TT is going to take loads. If it is weaker than expected, that's your eventual failure point. Did you have to sand all the way through the tube to remove all the frayed carbon? If so, then that failure point is quite worryingly big. Anyway, the worst case is that out of your sight, you get a crack propagating through the structure. Then, when it fails, it's a worse failure than you expected. Because the rest of the bike isn't supported, other tubes could then fail.
Basically, you may have seen the videos on YouTube by Predator Cycling, which sells home repair kits. I don't know how much I would trust an ordinary consumer to do a home repair. If you have previous exposure to building structural carbon components, like maybe you worked in aerospace, then sure, why not, but you proceed at your own risk and you need to continuously monitor the area for changes. If you have no previous experience, then it seems like more of a risk.

thanks for the comment. i am very hesitant about DIYing the repair for the reasons you stated. i'm trying to understand the risks better for this particular situation-- what exactly could happen if i overbuilt the top tube, in terms of mechanical forces?

Do you know how to overbuild it properly, though? I certainly do not. Nobody on the site does. You presumably do not, or you wouldn't be asking. I mean, consider this. Are you getting some plies of unidirectional CF and overlaying them? Do you know how to match the number of plies? Or are you using woven CF, which isn't unidirectional and which may have different material properties from the rest of the tube. Do you understand the implication of that? It might be trivial, it might be small but ignorable, but we don't know.

these are excellent questions that i do want to consider before attempting a repair. I don't know how important it is to understand these things. Do you? And to answer the first rhetorical question, i figured i would just add a few extra layers to thicken the tube beyond the original thickness.

Frames flex. One risk of "overbuilding", among others, is that one area is now much stiffer than the other components. Thus a shape that had distributed stresses evenly throughout is now focusing on a joint or boundary not intended to handle them. This is a very common theme in engineering disasters both small and large.

@JayMcEh from what I understand, stress risers usually happen when you don't taper the sanding enough (or generally if there is some "drop-off" in the old vs new material). would adding extra material cause additional stress?
